# One line bool from a QueryString

Tags: c#, refactoring

Is there a better way to write this

```
            string q = Request.QueryString["q"] ?? string.Empty;
            bool isSearch = q != string.Empty ? true : false;
```

Like a one-line statement?

Comment: You never need to write code like `if <something> return true; else return false;`  It is redundant; you are already evaluating a boolean expression, just use the result.  `isSearch = (q != String.Empty)`

Comment: This question is great for a speed typing contest :)

Comment: Oh wait how about.... oh nevermind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bool isSearch = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["q"]);
```

Comment: One thing to note about this solution is that it only works if the query string variable is not actually meant to be a bool. For example, if you have `?isSearch=false` that will evaluate to true using the above code. I realize this does not apply to this exact situation but Googling "C# QueryString to boolean" lands you here.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
bool isSearch = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["q"])
```

Comment: Ditto :-) Looks like 3 of us got it within a minute of each other.  But you were first so fair is fair.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
bool isSearch = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["q"]);
```